# Place widgets in stack according to their size

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have several widgets, each with the header at the top, the header is of uncertain size. I want to animate them between two states:

1. These widgets follow each other
2. These widgets overlap each other, only their headers are visible

Like in the following picture:

[image]

How to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your widgets to be scrollable, then I believe you'll find your answer with the sliver Widget. It scrolls and keep a header on top,stacking for each widget.

Comment: Thanks, but SliverList don't fit my needs: I need to animate these widgets in a different way, to provide custom behavior